# int to a uint8_t in HEX, for example 0x07 stored in a uint8_t. In C

Tags: c, timestamp, int, ibeacon, uint8t

I am trying to change the advert of my iBeacon sending the time stamp in the Major and Minor fields.
In the example code the Major an Minor are an uint8_t, so to get the date for example I use this:

```
uint8_t getConcatTimestamp(){
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm * timeinfo;
     char *bufferyear;
     char *buffermon;
     char *bufferday;
     char *bufferhour;
     char *buffermin;
     uint8_t segundos=0x10;
   time ( &rawtime );
   timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
   bufferyear = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) *4);
     buffermon = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) *4);
     bufferday = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) *4);
     bufferhour = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) *4);
     buffermin = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) *4);

   strftime (bufferyear,4,"%y",timeinfo);
     strftime (buffermon,4,"%m",timeinfo);
   strftime (bufferday,4,"%d",timeinfo);
   strftime (bufferhour,4,"%H",timeinfo);
   strftime (buffermin,4,"%M",timeinfo);
     segundos=(uint8_t)(timeinfo->tm_sec);
    //segundos=0x10;
 //return buffer;
    return(segundos);

}
```

In spite of using segundos as 0x10 it doesn't work and I don't know why. But the idea is to use for example segundos=(uint8_t)(timeinfo->tm_sec); because I pretend to extract each 16bits data (0x00, 2 HEX digits) to use them in the Major and Minor. I tried using the char strings using the char * buffers but I find harder to pass later from char to uint8_t the data, maybe is easier to work with the ints that I can get from the struct provided by:

```
struct tm {
   int tm_sec;         /* seconds,  range 0 to 59          */
   int tm_min;         /* minutes, range 0 to 59           */
   int tm_hour;        /* hours, range 0 to 23             */
   int tm_mday;        /* day of the month, range 1 to 31  */
   int tm_mon;         /* month, range 0 to 11             */
   int tm_year;        /* The number of years since 1900   */
   int tm_wday;        /* day of the week, range 0 to 6    */
   int tm_yday;        /* day in the year, range 0 to 365  */
   int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time             */   
};
```

And in the infinite for to advert with the iBeacon in the main class is the following:

```
// Enter main loop.
    for (;;)
    {
            seconds=getConcatTimestamp();
                if(cont<2)
                {   

                    flash_db_t tmp;
                    tmp.data.major_value[0] = clbeacon_info[18] = 0x00;
        tmp.data.major_value[1] = clbeacon_info[19] = 0x01;
        tmp.data.minor_value[0] = clbeacon_info[20] = 0x00;
                    if(cont==0)
                    {
                //tmp.data.minor_value[1] = clbeacon_info[21] = aesstruct.key[0];
                        tmp.data.minor_value[1] = clbeacon_info[21] = seconds;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    tmp.data.minor_value[1] = clbeacon_info[21] = aesstruct.key[1];
                    }
                    err_code = pstorage_clear(&pstorage_block_id, sizeof(flash_db_t));
        APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);

        err_code = pstorage_store(&pstorage_block_id, (uint8_t *)&tmp, sizeof(flash_db_t), 0);
        APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);

        err_code = pstorage_access_wait();
        APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
                    advertising_init(beacon_mode_normal);
        s_leds_bit_mask |= BEACON_MODE_LED_MSK;
                    //Solo esto estaba dentro del for(;;)
        app_sched_execute();
        power_manage();







                    cont++;

                }
                else
                    cont=0;
            }
}
```

Yes, I know that Major and Minor are 16 bits, but as this iBeacon firmware is built it uses an uint8_t array with 2 fields, both have 16 bits. This is in fact more or less the data structure I use:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t  magic_byte;
    uint8_t  beacon_uuid[16];    
    uint8_t  major_value[2];
    uint8_t  minor_value[2];
    uint8_t  measured_rssi;
}flash_db_layout_t;
```

Si that's why I need the data en uint8_t. And I want to send 128 bits, 4 complete packets with Minor and Major (32*4=128bits encrypted with AES). But first I need to get to send the time stamp in order to test. So, is there any example or snippet to know hoy to turn them into bytes? but won't I need uint8_t in the end? Because when I upload the firmware the device doesn't work and I guess that it must be because a wrong type of data

Comment: Major and minor are 16 bit and so should not be a uint8_t but rather either a uint16_t or a uint8_t* or a uint8_t[2].  Likely you should get your timestamp as a uint32_t and then assign it to bytes in pieces.  It will be more portable if you do that with shift operations rather than pointer games.

Comment: I have added some info related with that. As you said I use an uint8_t[2] in order to store the 16 bits. In the question I've posted the data structure used. The problem is that I have to send 2 uint8_t to send the Major data for example, if I had the bits I would need the uin8_t anyway.

Comment: So it seems to be a hard question because I can't find any answer at the moment